# How to make the image box under the button in React

Tags: css, reactjs, image, button

I have a layout like this. What I want is to let the image box next to the Render 3D button move below the button:
[image]

My Code is here

```
<div id="modeling">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-8"> 
              <div className="modeling-text">
                <h2>3D MODELING</h2>
                <h3>Upload a 2D image to get a 3D model</h3>        
                
                <input className="btn btn-secondary" id="fileInput" name="file" type="file" onChange={fileChangedHandler} />
               
                <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{float:"left", marginLeft: "10px"}} ng-click="showConfirm() "
                        ng-if="fileName.length > 0"  id="renderButton">
                  Render 3D Model
                </button>
          
                <img src={file} alt={""} width="300" height="300" text-align="left" />
              
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Can someone help me to move this? Thanks a lot

Comment: You are placing both button and image inside a row.. So consider moving the image outside the ```row``` class like, https://codesandbox.io/s/freecodecamp-recipe-box-forked-m4qgd

Comment: Also make sure you have mentioned the right tags in question.. Because you mention ```reactjs``` in tag but posted the code related to ```angularjs``` .. Eg: ```ng-click="showConfirm() "``` ..

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of that.. You can post another question and people who knows will answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just display it as `block`

```
<img src={file} alt={""} width="300" height="300" text-align="left" style={{display:'block'}} />
```